# Uipath - Unable to perform API call using post method

Tags: rpa, uipath

So, I am trying to replicate the process I automated using Excel VBA+Selenium to UiPath.
In that, the first step is to get a set of details from a table stored in a database using API.
So I created an HTTP request under a sequence and enter the URL and added the parameters table name and API key. I did a preview, and I was able to view the data as the API call was success.

And when I run the HTTP request it shows me an error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary UiPath

I did some google research with the above error but no luck so came here.

I have added the screenshots of Workflow and error message.

[image: Work Flow]

[image: Error Message]

kwoxer - Kindly find below the screen shots.
This is the complete workflow
[image: Complete workflow]

This is where I added the variables, also when I did a preview I was able to get the details from the data base.
[image: Adding variables]

Comment: Can you show the whole Main sequence? And show the Locals variables when it fails. Where does that popup came from?

Comment: Can you show the whole Main sequence? Sure, but there is nothing in the sequence as this is first step of the process- I have added the same in the above question.
The variables is added in the HTTP wizard - added the same in the main question
The pop up comes once I run the sequence.

Comment: Error is very generic. You are using dictionary and trying to access via key but that key is not present in the dictionary